# Different ways of python importing

Tags: python, import, pytorch

I want to know the difference between two kinds of ways of import

Option 1

```
import torch
fc=torch.nn.Linear()
```

Option 2

```
from torch.nn import Linear
fc=Linear()
```

thanks for answering my question
. on the basis, is there a difference between these two?

```
import torch.nn

from torch import nn
```

Comment: The first imports the entire module of torch. Which is importing its \_\_init__.py file, including everything that comes with  it. You can do `dir(torch)` to see what else were made available when you imported the entire module. The second is more specific and imports only the `Linear` class from the `nn` module, which does not include all the other stuff you don't need

Comment: in simple terms, the first gives you access to everything in the module (so more useful if you will use many methods), whereas the second is giving access to just the item that is imported (so more useful if you are just using only one or two methods).